# The title of my UIButton with UIVibrancyEffect is not visible when backgroundColor is assigned

Tags: swift, uibutton, ios9, uivisualeffectview

I have two buttons added to `UIVisualEffectView`with effect `UIVibrancyEffect`:

```
let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)))

vibrancyEffectView.contentView.addSubview(rightActionButton)
vibrancyEffectView.contentView.addSubview(leftActionButton)
```

[image]

the nest is set Title for them:

```
rightActionButton.setTitle(rightAction.title, forState: .Normal)
leftActionButton.setTitle(leftAction?.title, forState: .Normal)
```

And `backgroundColor`:

```
leftActionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
rightActionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Why I cannot see the right title? How to fix this?

Below is example from Apple, exactly what I need to do:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a backgroundColor with alpha component.

```
let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)))

leftActionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
rightActionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
```

And the result is following:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The title is there but you cannot see it because it has the same color as it background. To use `UIVibrancyEffect` button background color **must** be set to clear color so this way all transparent pixels that are multiply with their corresponding background pixels will result in transparent as well. To fix this:

```
rightActionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: I know, it is there, but I need to make it visible with backgroundColor. Your answer is not reply for my question. Any other ideas?